# Using Django to send Gmail

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, dns, django-email

This is very much potentially a duplicate question, but none of the other obvious duplicates have resolved the issue for me:

This is an inherited project.

My `settings.py` includes:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_username@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_password'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my_username@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_FEEDBACK_EMAIL = 'my_username@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'my_username@gmail.com'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

The code that I'm trying to run is:

```
subject = 'Subject'
template = get_template('accounts/email-templates/email-activation.html').render(Context(ctx))
email = EmailMessage(subject, template, to=[send_to])
        email.content_subtype = "html"
try:
   email.send()
```

My error when trying repeatedly with `python manage.py shell` is:

```
gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

My dns seems fine, `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` and `dscacheutil -flushcache` have been run without success, but I'm hardly an expert on dns settings.
My hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Advice appreciated!

Comment: what's the full stack trace when you run it without the "try:"?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to generate an app password in Gmail or change the settings to [allow less secure access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en). I don't think Gmail will allow you to just use your regular password in - what Google would consider - an insecure manner.

Comment: I tried these things already, unfortunately. I think the problem is on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem working with Gmail to send mails.

Try only the following codes to send emails. Hope it helps:

> In settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "sender_email@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "email_password"
EMAIL_PORT = 0
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

> Codes to send emails:

```
# Imports for sending emails:
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives, send_mail

emailFrom = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
emailTo = email_here
text_content = 'Your content here'
email_subject = "Subject here"
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(email_subject, text_content, emailFrom, [emailTo], )
msg.send()
```

Also change the [settings](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) in the 'sender gmail account' to create a passage for the mail to be send from the sender to the receiver. Hope this helps.